# View Logs in Azure Service Fabric with SF CLI (sfctl)

Tags: logging, azure-service-fabric

I am new to Azure Service Fabric and C# and I'm looking for an equivalent to "kubectl logs -f" in sfctl.
Is there any other way to view the stdout log of a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as easy as with Kubernetes, but the [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-overview) approach is:

1. Application monitoring with [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-monitoring-aspnet)
2. Cluster monitoring with Diagnostics Agent and [Azure Monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-oms-setup)
3. Infrastructure monitoring with [Azure Monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-oms-agent)

In your case, you'd use App Insights to see Service traces and logs. Make sure to enable '[developer mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#developer-mode)' locally, to decrease the time it takes for logs to show up.